# Países baixos ou Holanda, qual o mais correto?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras

Países baixos ou Holanda, qual o mais correto?

Costumo  ouvir os dois.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O correto é Países Baixos.

A Holanda é apenas uma província dos Países Baixos.
Acontece muito chamar-se ao país [Holanda](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holanda_(top%C3%B4nimo)), mas isso é um erro:

> Os Países Baixos são comumente conhecidos em português como Holanda, todavia esta é uma denominação imprópria, pois Holanda é apenas uma das regiões dos Países Baixos, hoje formada pelas províncias da Holanda Setentrional e Holanda Meridional. Em 2019, o governo dos Países Baixos lançou uma campanha para que a nação seja mundialmente conhecida pelo seu nome correto e que o topônimo "Holanda" seja evitado para fazer menção a todo o país.

O mesmo acontece com a Grã-Bretanha ou Reino Unido, ao qual frequentemente se chama [Inglaterra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inglaterra) - mas esta é apenas uma região/país da ilha e da nação/país.
Um país ser constituido por vários países ([1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esc%C3%B3cia), [2](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inglaterra), [3](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irlanda_do_Norte), [4](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pa%C3%ADs_de_Gales)), não ajuda...